# Server sending Empty file to client

Tags: java, sockets, file-transfer

Server Side code

```
int count=-1;
byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [1024];

BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(myFile));
os = s.getOutputStream();

System.out.println("Sending " + fileName + "(" + mybytearray.length + " bytes)");
while( (count=(bis.read(mybytearray)))>0) {
    System.out.println(count);
    os.write(mybytearray,0,count);
    os.flush();
}
System.out.println("Done.");                      
bis.close(); 
os.close();
```

Client Side code

```
int bytesRead=-1;
byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [1024];
InputStream isP = p2p.getInputStream();
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path+"RFC "+rfcNum+".txt");
while((bytesRead=isP.read(mybytearray))>0) {
fos.write(mybytearray, 0, bytesRead);
fos.flush();
fileSize+=bytesRead;
 } 
System.out.println("file Size is "+fileSize);
isP.close();
fos.close();
```

i am getting an empty file from server to client . Even though at the server it is printing the the bytearray size which is not zero. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: @IstvanChung: tried that too.Still not working

Comment: Don't flush inside the loop. It destroys the point of using buffered streams.

Answer (score 0):

> i am getting an empty file from server to client.

With that code, the file must be empty at the server too.

> Even though at the server it is printing the the bytearray size which is not zero.

That's because you initialized it as 'new byte[1024]'. It has nothing to do with the length of the file.